# Get-PrintConfiguration doesnt seem to work

Tags: powershell, printing, configuration

I am trying to use Get-PrintConfiguration on a networked printer but for some reason it returns this error

> Get-PrintConfiguration : The specified printer was not found. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "Printer1"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_PrinterConfiguration:ROOT/StandardCi...erConfiguration)
>   [Get-PrintConfiguration], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Get-PrintConfiguration

Is there something I am missing? The Printer name is correct and im somewhat confident the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: 
I just noticed the second line. If you're specifying a printer name by concatenating multiple strings, be sure to surround the concatenations with parenthese. Example:

```
Get-PrinterConfiguration -PrinterName ("Printer1" + "-PC1")
```

Hope some of this helps.

Original:
Only posting this as an answer since I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, but in order to get a proper answer, could you provide more details, please? Perhaps a code/script example?

This worked for me to get a network printer configuration

```
Get-Printer | Where-Object -Property 'Name' -EQ 'Sharp MX-4140N' | Get-PrintConfiguration

PrinterName     ComputerName    Collate    Color      DuplexingMode       
-----------     ------------    -------    -----      -------------       
Sharp MX-4140N                  True       True       OneSided
```

Note: computer name blanked intentionally.